# How to uninstall GNUStep?

Tags: uninstall

In a fit of command line joy, I went about installing some programs. I tried to install the 'say' command (like Darwin has), and installed whatever program Ubuntu recommended -- unfortunately, without writing it down.

It ended up not being the right one, and I'm pretty sure I downloaded GNUStep -- there's not a folder in my home directory, and if I delete it and run 'say' again, it recreates and  creates an 'installed-software.txt' file.

How do I uninstall GNUstep, and stop this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After run `say` Ubuntu recommends installation of gnustep-gui-runtime. Uninstall it by running:

```
sudo apt-get remove gnustep-gui-runtime
```

You can also run `sudo apt-get autoremove` to remove the automatically installed dependencies of gnustep-gui-runtime.

Answer (score 1):

If you just installed it via `apt-get install <packagename>` (or, as it would be, `sudo apt-get install <packagename>`), you can uninstall it via `apt-get remove <packagename>` (or, if you need root permissions (which you probably do) `sudo apt-get remove <packagename>`.

In your case this would (probably) be `sudo apt-get remove gnustep`.

Comment: Thank you for your help! It has helped me to understand the uninstallation process more fully.